# unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have the following simple code:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;

class KeyEventDemo {
    static void main(String[] args) {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
    } 
}
```

It generates the following error message:

```
KeyEventDemo.java:7: unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
                            ^
1 error
```

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, the message is self explaining: [`UIManager.setLookAndFeel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#setLookAndFeel%28java.lang.String%29) throws a bunch of **checked** exceptions that thus need to be caught (with a try/catch block) or declared to be thrown (in the calling method).

So either surround the call with a try/catch:

```
public class KeyEventDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            // TODO handle me
        } catch ( InstantiationException e ) {
            // TODO handle me
        } catch ( IllegalAccessException e ) {
            // TODO handle me
        } catch ( UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e ) {
            // TODO handle me
        }
    }
}
```

Or add a throws declaration:

```
public class KeyEventDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, 
        InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, 
        UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
    }
}
```

If you don't want to handle each of them in a specific way, this can be made less verbose by using the `Exception` supertype:

```
public class KeyEventDemo {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO handle me
        }
    }
}
```

Or with a throws declaration (note that this convey less information to the caller of the method but the caller being the JVM here, it doesn't really matter in this case):

```
class KeyEventDemo {
    static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me which "checked exception" I have. To me it looks similar to "try... except..." construction in Pyhon. So, Python tries to do something and if a command does not "want" to do something it generates a type error message. But what is the "error message" in my case? What should be my Exception?

Comment: Do you mean the exact exception type you need to declare? It's "ClassNotFoundException", as given in the error message.

Answer (score 4):

Redefine your method to be

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```